# Trouble in removing ms teams application from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-teams

I used the command below to remove teams permanently:

```
sudo apt purge teams
```

However, when I check with `sudo apt list | grep teams` I see the app names below:

```
(base) user@user-pc:~$ sudo apt list | grep teams

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

python3-openid-teams/focal,focal 1.2-2 all
t1-teams/focal,focal 4.17 all
teams-insiders/stable 1.5.00.10453 amd64
teams/stable 1.5.00.10453 amd64
```

When I attempt to remove those apps, it can't find them. Also, when I reinstall Teams, it remembers my user name from the previous login. This indicates that there are still some config or log files somewhere.

How can I completely remove the Microsoft Teams app (with all config files and preferences) from my Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score 1):

You said that you purged the `teams` packages and then reinstalled them. `apt list` shows all packages that are available, installed, and that can be upgraded which includes literally every package. If you run `apt list --installed | grep teams`, then you won't see those packages.

The config files for your user info, personal settings, etc are located in your home the following subdirectories:

```
~/.config/teams
~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams
```

Delete those folders:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/teams
rm -rf "~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams"
```

Comment: What do you say about the apps seen in list as `teams-insiders/stable 1.5.00.10453 amd64` and `teams/stable 1.5.00.10453 amd64`

Comment: @ibilgen I updated the my answer. I didn't mention that previously because he said the he had already uninstalled and then reinstalled the packages. The issue that he's having is with getting rid of the configs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, somehow the question I asked looks like asked by a new user, so I can't accept your answer although I can edit the question. I think because of an error or bug of StackExchange.